# Clarification on a lemma for Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

The lemma:
Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group and suppose that $g\in G$ has maximal order. Then G is isomorphic to $\langle g\rangle\times H$ for some subgroup $H$ of $G$.

The proof I am reading is here, Lemma $13.9$:
http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/section-finite-abelian-groups.html

I understand all until the following part:
[image]

I have the following question:

1. Why order of $gH$ in the factor group $G/H$ MUST $=p^m$?
2. Why $gH$ MUST have maximum order in $G/H$??
3. Our induction hypothesis is $G=\langle g\rangle\times K$, so we divide the equation by $H$ and it becomes isomorphism $G/H\cong \langle gH\rangle\times K/H$? Also $\langle g\rangle/H=\langle gH\rangle$??

Comment: 1. Because they are proving it can’t be any smaller. 2. Because you know it has the same order as the largest possible order in $G$, and orders in the quotient can’t be bigger than orders in the group. 3. No, the induction hypothesis is that for smaller groups the conclusion holds for $G/H$, not for $G$. So $G/H$ can be expressed as $\langle gH\rangle \times M$ for some $M$, and this $M$ can be expressed as $K/H$ by the isomorphism theorems.